# How to set RDP session to be always logged in on Windows Server 2008?

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, exchange-2007, remote-desktop

I'm having problem with my Remote Desktop session to Exchange Server as myself always gets logged off everynight ?

I need to scheduled Exchange Management Console to run after the office hours but it always failed since my RDP session gets logged off overnight, is there any way to configure it to stay logged on (Windows Server 2008) please ?

Thanks.

Comment: May I ask what you are doing that requires a user logged in?  Are you sure you can't fix whatever is happening to work in the background?

Comment: I'm doing the Exchange Server mailbox migration using the Exchange management Console to schedule after the office hour migration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the user-properties, (Local Users and Groups > User > Right click > Properties) there should be a tab 'sessions'.
You should be able to disable the automatic logoff behavior there.

If you want this for all users, edit gpedit.msc.
You can set the period to a max of 2 days in Computer Configuration -> Administrative Templates -> Windows Components -> Terminal Services - > Session